# Accept x-www-form-urlencoded in Asp .net core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core(2.1) Web API that has to adapt to an existed .Net framework(4.6.2)  system, and the existed system send a request that the Api accepts.

Here is the problem. In the .Net framework system, it calls the api like this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xxx.xxx/CloudApi/RegionsList");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Accept = "*/*";

var data = new Person()
{
    Name = "Alex",
    Age = 40
};
byte[] dataBuffer;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); formatter.Serialize(ms, data);
    dataBuffer = ms.GetBuffer();
}

request.ContentLength = dataBuffer.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
requestStream.Close();

try
{
     var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
     Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
}
```

Here is the api controller code:

```
[Route("cloudapi")]
public class LegacyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("regionslist")]
    public dynamic RegionsList([FromBody]byte[] value)
    {
        return value.Length;
    }
}
```

Person class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

According to this article: [Accepting Raw Request Body Content in ASP.NET Core API Controllers](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers)

I have made a custom InputFormatter to deal with this case:

```
public class RawRequestBodyFormatter : IInputFormatter
{
    public RawRequestBodyFormatter()
    {

    }

    public bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("argument is Null");
        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (contentType == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (contentType == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
                {
                    await request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    var content = ms.ToArray();

                    return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
                }
            }
        }
        return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
    }
}
```

But I found that the data I send(the Person class instance) was not in request.Body but in request.Form, and I can't deserialize it Form.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering why you need read the raw `byte[]` ?

Comment: @itminus Need to convert to the object which passed by the http request, which is made by the exsited client(the old .Net framework system) that I can't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you need to read the raw `Request.Body`, it's better to enable rewind feature.
2. [`InputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is overkill for this scenario. `InputFormatter` cares about content negotiation. Typically, we use it in this way : if the client sends a payload of `application/json`, we shoud do A ; if the client sends a payload of `application/xml`, we should do B . But your client (legacy system) only sends `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Rather than creating `InputFormatter`, you could create a dead simple `ModelBinder` to deserialize the payload.
3. Hack:  Your legacy `.Net framework(4.6.2)` system use `BinaryFormatter` to serialize the `Person` class, and your `.NET Core` website needs to deserialize it to an object of `Person`. Typically, this requires your `.NET Core` app and the Legacy `.NET Framework` system  share the same `Person` assembly. **But obviously the original `Person` targets `.NET Framewrok 4.6.2`, in other words, this assembly cannot be referenced by `.NET Core`**. A walkaround is to create a type that shares the same name of `Person`, and create a `SerializationBinder` to bind a new type.

Suppose in your `Person` class of the Legacy system is :

```
namespace App.Xyz{

    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You should create a same class in your `.NET Core` WebSite:

```
namespace App.Xyz{

    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note the namespace should also keep the same.

**How to in details.**

1. Create a `Filter` that enables `Rewind` for `Request.Body`

   ```
   public class EnableRewindResourceFilterAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
   {
       public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context) { }

       public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
       {
           context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now you can create a `ModelBinder`:

   ```
   public class BinaryBytesModelBinder: IModelBinder
   {
       internal class LegacyAssemblySerializationBinder : SerializationBinder 
       {
           public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName) {
               var typeToDeserialize = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
                   .GetType(typeName);   // we use the same typename by convention
               return typeToDeserialize;
           }
       }

       public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {
           if (bindingContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext)); }
           var modelName = bindingContext.BinderModelName?? "LegacyBinaryData";

           var req = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
           var raw= req.Body;
           if(raw == null){ 
               bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName,"invalid request body stream");
               return Task.CompletedTask;
           }
           var formatter= new BinaryFormatter();
           formatter.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
           formatter.Binder = new LegacyAssemblySerializationBinder();
           var o = formatter.Deserialize(raw);
           bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(o);
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, decorate your action method with the `Filter`, and use the model binder to retrieve the instance :

   ```
   [Route("cloudapi")]
   public class LegacyController : ControllerBase
   {
       [EnableRewindResourceFilter]
       [HttpPost]
       [Route("regionslist")]
       public dynamic RegionsList([ModelBinder(typeof(BinaryBytesModelBinder))] Person person )
       {
           // now we gets the person here
       }
   }
   ```

a demo :

[image]

---

#### Alternative Approach : Use `InputFormatter` (not suggested)

Or if you do want to use `InputFormatter`, you should also enable rewind:

```
[Route("cloudapi")]
public class LegacyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableRewindResourceFilter]
    [Route("regionslist")]
    public dynamic RegionsList([FromBody] byte[] bytes )
    {

        return new JsonResult(bytes);
    }
}
```

and configure the services :

```
services.AddMvc(o => {
    o.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawRequestBodyFormatter());
});
```

And also, you should deserialize the person object in the same way as we do in Model Binder.

But be careful the performance!

Answer (score 2):

I know there is an already accepted response, but I came up with a way of parsing the request.Form data and rebuilding the content into an original request.Body format:

```
public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var contentType = request.ContentType;
    if (contentType.StartsWith("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")) // in case it ends with ";charset=UTF-8"
    {
        var content = string.Empty;
        foreach (var key in request.Form.Keys)
        {
            if (request.Form.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                content += $"{key}={value}&";
            }
        }
        content = content.TrimEnd('&');
        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
    }
    return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
}
```